# I can't install pywin32 or pypiwin32 in python

Tags: python

HELP ME PlEASE!!!
Even though I tried downloading it over and over again, I still couldn't download it.
pip3 install pywin32
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
pip3 install pypiwin32
Collecting pypiwin32
Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pypiwin32 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Using cached pypiwin32-219.zip (4.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [22 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in 
main()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/private/var/folders/np/j0b1hzy156ncglb74zdj8hcw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-11jntcle/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/private/var/folders/np/j0b1hzy156ncglb74zdj8hcw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-11jntcle/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "/private/var/folders/np/j0b1hzy156ncglb74zdj8hcw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-11jntcle/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
File "/private/var/folders/np/j0b1hzy156ncglb74zdj8hcw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-11jntcle/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 121
print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

pip3 install pywin32
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32
pip3 install pypiwin32
Collecting pypiwin32
Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pypiwin32 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Using cached pypiwin32-219.zip (4.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [22 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in 
main()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/private/var/folders/np/j0b1hzy156ncglb74zdj8hcw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-11jntcle/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/private/var/folders/np/j0b1hzy156ncglb74zdj8hcw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-11jntcle/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "/private/var/folders/np/j0b1hzy156ncglb74zdj8hcw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-11jntcle/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
File "/private/var/folders/np/j0b1hzy156ncglb74zdj8hcw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-11jntcle/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 121
print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the file paths in your error messages, it looks like you are trying to install `pywin32` on a Linux system, which is why it is failing.

`pywin32` is only available for Windows systems, as it relies on Windows DLLs.  You will need to work on a Windows computer to work with the `pywin32` package.

The specific reason for the error message:

> SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)? [end of output]

is because on Linux, pip can't find a current version and tries to install an old cached build (Version 223 from February 2018), which is a Python 2.7 version of the package.  In Python 2, `print` was a keyword and not a function, so `print "Building pywin32"` was valid Python2 code, but crashes in Python3.

I can only assume that version was marked as being ok for Linux at some point, but I don't know if it was intentional or accidental.